# MySQL, Insert Row in-between two others

Tags: mysql

I'm coding a website for a photographer and I'm currently working on gallery implimentation.
I need to be able to take a row from point n.a and move it to point n.b
Here's an example of the raw table:

```
|gallery_img               |
|--------------------------|
| id | fk_gal | fk_img | o |
|    |        |        |   |
| 0  | 16     | 240    | 1 |
| 1  | 16     | 322    | 2 |
| 2  | 27     | 240    | 1 |
| 3  | 16     | 245    | 3 |
| 4  | 16     | 210    | 4 |
| 5  | 27     | 530    | 2 |
```

All fields are INT(11). 'id' Auto_increments. 'fk_gal' and 'fk_img' are linked to other, irrelevant, tables via FOREIGN_KEY.

Now, 'o' is the field I'm focusing on. It determines what order the images will be displayed on the website. This value needs to always be unique for each table. To clarify, If I only call one table, 'o' should be different in every row. However, if I call the entire table, 'o[0]' might reoccur a few times.

So here's what I need. Firstly, I'm only going to be running this function on only one gallery at a time so all visuals of the table from here on out are going to be filtered with 'SELECT * FROM gallery_img WHERE fk_gal = 16'.
I need to change 'o' from n to n2 which will effectively move it on the database.

```
|gallery_img               |
|--------------------------|
| id | fk_gal | fk_img | o |
|    |        |        |   |
| 0  | 16     | 240    | 1 |
|    |        |        |   |  <--
| 1  | 16     | 322    | 2 |+   |
| 3  | 16     | 245    | 3 |+   |
| 4  | 16     | 210    | 4 |  --|
```

The code needs to move the desired row (in this example 'o=4') to 1 and simultaneously move all of the next rows down to prevent any reoccurrences.
Here's my code I have right now. I'm coding my MySql scripts via PHP.
I am using the $n variable here. It includes the following data:

$n = array(gallery_id,img_id,target_o);

```
            sql("UPDATE gallery_img SET o = o + 1 ORDER BY o ASC LIMIT ". ($n[2] - 1) .", 18446744073709551615;");
            sql("UPDATE gallery_img SET o = ". ($n[2] + 2) ." WHERE fk_img = $n[1] AND fk_gal = $n[0];");
```

The problem I'm having with this is that when I execute it I get one of these two outputs:

```
|gallery_img               |
|--------------------------|
| id | fk_gal | fk_img | o |
|    |        |        |   |
| 0  | 16     | 240    | 1 |
| 4  | 16     | 210    | 1 | <-- Shouldn't be duplicate
| 1  | 16     | 322    | 2 |
| 3  | 16     | 245    | 3 |


|gallery_img               |
|--------------------------|
| id | fk_gal | fk_img | o |
|    |        |        |   |
| 0  | 16     | 240    | 1 |
| 4  | 16     | 210    | 2 |
| 1  | 16     | 322    | 4 |-|
| 3  | 16     | 245    | 4 | |-- Shouldn't be duplicate
| 5  | 16     | 273    | 4 | |
| 6  | 16     | 14     | 4 |-|
```

A good way to think of it is as so:

```
UPDATE
```

If you have any questions please let me know!
Thanks ahead of time for your help!

Comment: I don't get what you're after

Comment: Yeah it's really hard to explain XD. Let me try to clarify.

Comment: What's that arbitrary huge number junk doing in your `LIMIT` statement? Just use `OFFSET` with no `LIMIT` if you want to start at one point.

Comment: "_The code needs to move the desired row (in this example 'o=4') to 1_" Looking at your table you already have an img with `o=1`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: `UPDATE gallery_img SET o = (o + 1) WHERE o >= ($n[2] + 2)` then `UPDATE gallery_img SET o = ($n[2] + 2) WHERE fk_img = $n[1] AND fk_gal = $n[0]` maybe.

Comment: @tadman that's what I'm doing, 'id' isn't being touched. I'm only altering 'o'. then when I call the table I order it by 'o'.
"SELECT * FROM gallery_img ORDER BY o ASC".
Also to touch on your warning. I do have the correct security messures in plas, I've omited them for simplicities sake. I do appreceate it tho!

Comment: @kerbholz correct. Before changing 'o=4' to 'o=1'. I need to take the original 'o=1' and change it to 'o=2' (and then do the same for each next row)

Comment: Keep in mind it's usually simpler *with* placeholder values because we can more easily see the structure of your query. It also assures us you're taking this responsibility seriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you're wanting to change the row WHERE `o=4` to `o=1` then increment the number to be replaced and all greater numbers.

```
UPDATE gallery_img SET o = (o + 1) WHERE o >= 1
```

Then update the row that you want to be `o=1`:

```
UPDATE gallery_img SET o = 1 WHERE fk_img = something1 AND fk_gal = something2
```

Or if you only know the `o` use `o=(4+1)` since it changed in the last UPDATE:

```
UPDATE gallery_img SET o = 1 WHERE o = 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest a hack? For the column `o` don't use an integer number, but a `DOUBLE PRECISION` one.

It would be much easier to insert a row in between, just by averaging the values of the previous and next row. If you need to insert between `3` and `4`, you can just insert a row with `3.5`.

Of course, after some time (after 50 times at least) you would like to re-number those values, since a `DOUBLE PRECISION` has 53 bits for the mantissa.

Comment: That's a really good thought! I considered something similar, but I really wanted it to be completly self sufficient.